# Appgyver loading screen doesn't hide

Tags: android, steroids

I'm new to Steroids and when I create new app and run in on my device (Philips W8555, Android 4.2.2) - loading screen doesn't hide! This screen has opacity, so I can see elements (text, buttons, selects, etc) on the page, I can interact with them, but loading screen always shows. I try to rename www/loading.html, but nothing happens. This is screenshot (i can't post images):

https://pp.vk.me/c620524/v620524099/a782/0Cgjka947TA.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in AppGyver's legacy Android runtime, as documented [here](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/381). Essentially, the active WebView has a transparent background, so you can see through to the loading screen (which is below it). To circumvent the issue, manually set an opaque background for your WebViews, e.g.

```
body {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to the newest AppGyver Android client version (4.x) and YOU_GOOD!